# Device to remove loud pops when plugging in audio equipment?

Tags: audio, speakers, audio-adapters

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323356/loud-pop-noise-while-plugging-to-a-headphones-jack) explains the electronics of the problem, and several solutions to fix it by DIY'ing a solution.  I am worried that these crazy loud pops will damage my speakers.  I run into this problem when plugging in a new source (phone, laptop, tablet, etc.) into some PC speakers (analog, or with a USB-C dock or adapter).

I'd like to buy a cheap little adapter thingey and put them in several places where I encounter this issue to protect my equipment.  I was able to find some [ground loop isolators](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XQYN77L) on Amazon for about $8, and they are solving another, different, problem that I run into.  They partially mitigate the insertion-popping problem, but there is the inevitable cackling and popping if the cable moves even the slightest, which is not at all mitigated by the ground loop isolator, and can also damage my speakers in the same way.

Does such an off-the-shelf product thing exist?  **If so, what is it called?**

So far my searches are getting crazy results, including on page 2 stuff related to *plumbing* (?!?).  I'm not sure what's up with that, so I figured I'd ask here.  Yes this is related to PC hardware, as my PC speakers have a 2nd input specifically for these purposes.  Klipsh and Altec Lansing mostly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to limit volume is to add a voltage limiter circuit to the input. The circuit below could be inserted at the input of each amplifier, or in a box which plugs into the amp.

[image: Volume Limiter]

One circuit is needed for each input. A single silicon diode in each leg will limit input to about .6 V, which might be too low for your needs. Wire *two* diodes in series, pointing the same way, in each leg, to increase maximum input volume to ~1.2 V.

Also, ground the chassis of each unit to a *common* ground. Using wires from one component to one AC outlet ground, and from another component, to another ground, can introduce a ground loop with concomitant AC hum.